# Preg replace URL with links: MIME types failure

Tags: php, regex, url, preg-replace, mime-types

I use the following regexp in a php function to replace URLs with proper HTML links:

```
return preg_replace('@(https?://([-\w\.]+[-\w])+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.#-]*(\?\S+)?[^\.\s])?)?)@', '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>', $s);
```

But when $s has for value a string like

```
<li>http://www.link.com/something.pdf</li>
```

the function returns

```
<li><a href="http://www.link.com/something.pdf</li">http://www.link.com/something.pdf</li></a></li>
```

Does anyone know how to modify the regexp to get the intended string, i.e.

```
<li><a href="http://www.link.com/something.pdf">http://www.link.com/something.pdf</a></li> ?
```

without excluding from the replacement substrings of the URL introduced by '%', '?' or '&' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really easy solution:

```
return '<li>'.preg_replace('@(https?://([-\w.]+[-\w])+(:\d+)?(/([\w-.~:/?#\[\]\@!$&\'()*+,;=%]*)?)?)@', '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>', $s).'</li>';
```

If you really want a regex:

```
return preg_replace('@(https?://([-\w.]+[-\w])+(:\d+)?(/([\w-.~:/?#\[\]\@!$&\'()*+,;=%]*)?)?)@', '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>', $s);
```

Comment: Thanks, but not quite. If I applied your solution, my surrounding "<li></li>" would be gone. Isn't it possible to exclude the </li> from the link without ruining the layout, so that I get exactly something in the form of my last code line?

Comment: Thank you, two last problems:
(i) too loose: some "<" still get in the replacement
(ii) too tight: some "&" (used as php variables separator) are still not caught in the replacement

Comment: I edited my regex, if it doesn't work, please check my first solution which is also working I think.

Comment: Awesome ! I think some '%' might still get through, but this is a huge improvement on what I had ! Thank you so much and have a beautiful day.

Comment: added %: preg_replace('@(https?://([-\w.]+[-\w])+(:\d+)?(/([\w-.~:/?#\[\]\@!$&\'()*+,;=%]*)?)?)@', '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>', $s);

Comment: This is it. Nice one Louix XIV !

Answer (score 0):

You rpattern is not sufficient (to catch all the links), but anyway, instead of `\S+` you might want to have `[^\s<>]+` because the former catches everything non-space.

Same applies to `[^\.\s]`. Make this `[^\s<>.]`. You don't *need* to escape the dot when used in a character class, so my addition to this group was basically the greater than and less than signs.

Comment: Thanks inhan, but this of course destroys all the php variables (and any character after '%') in the URL since it leaves '?' out of the replacement and stops at '%'. Without these two problems, it would be fine ... (I wish a knew more about regexp, sorry.)

Comment: `\S` means `[^\s]`. All I did was to add `<` and `>` signs to this unwanted character range.

Comment: Sorry inhan, but whenever there is a pattern like 'longLink.html?id=...' or 'longLink%C3%' in the URL, the replacement leaves anything after '?' or '%' out of the link.

Comment: You would better search for or build a better rule for url matching anyway. I just tried to patch yours.

Comment: Thanks, I wish I knew how to build one. And I didn't find any specific rule able to do the job.